How to remove double-quotes and \ in jq output without making it single line in bash?
I have the following json output
{
  "secrets": [
    [
      "{",
      "  \"name\": \"testSecret\",",
      "  \"vault-apikey\": \"kv\",",
      "  \"vault-value\": \"sabrinaTest\"",
      "}"
    ]
  ]
}

But I need the output to be a little cleaner and look like this:
{
  "secrets": [
    [
        {
           "name" : "testSecret",
           "vault-apikey" : "kv",
           "vault-value" : "sabrinaTest"
        }
    ]
  ]
}

These are the commands that I'm currently running to get this output:
TEST_SECRET_JSON=$(hcp vault-secrets secrets open testSecret --format=json)

SECRETS_INFO=$(echo $TEST_SECRET_JSON | jq -r '{"name": .name, "vault-apikey": .type, "vault-value": .static_version.value}')

jq -n --arg value "${SECRETS_INFO}" '{ secrets : [ $value | split("\n") ] }' >> secret.json

I have tried other variations, but none have produced the desired results.

Don't forget to quote $TEST_SECRET_JSON

SECRETS_INFO is already a jq object; use --argjson instead of --arg.
$ jq -n --argjson value "${SECRETS_INFO}" '{ secrets : [ $value ] }'
{
  "secrets": [
    {
      "name": "testSecret",
      "vault-apikey": "kv",
      "vault-value": "sabrinaTest"
    }
  ]
}

Or, just pipe the object into jq as input.
echo "$SECRETS_INFO" | jq '{ secrets : [.] }'


Or hcp … | jq '{secrets: [{name, "vault-apikey": .type, "vault-value": .static_version.value}]}' in the first place, if the intermediate Bash variables aren't needed elsewhere.

Yeah, I was just too lazy to collapse the entire snippet into a single command :)

Issue is the way you are handling jq to handle the formatting. You're splitting the JSON string into separate lines, but what you need is to parse and preserve it as an object. Here is a better approach

Use jq to create the desired JSON structure directly, without splitting it to two lines.
Ensure that the output from the vault-secrets command is parsed as JSON.

TEST_SECRET_JSON=$(hcp vault-secrets secrets open testSecret --format=json)

# Parse the necessary fields and construct the JSON structure
SECRETS_INFO=$(echo $TEST_SECRET_JSON | jq -c '{"name": .name, "vault-apikey": .type, "vault-value": .static_version.value}')

# Use jq to construct the final JSON
jq -n --argjson value "$SECRETS_INFO" '{ secrets: [ [$value] ] }' >> secret.json


I have managed to achieve the desired result using "awk" .
awk -F '\\' ' n=0 ; /\[/ {n=1} { if(!n){sub(/"/,"",$0) ; sub(/,$/,"",$0) ; sub(/"$/,"",$0) } ; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s",$i } printf "\n" }' jsonfile.txt

"jsonfile.txt" - the file you are working on.
Result -
{
  "secrets": [
    [
      {
        "name": "testSecret",
        "vault-apikey": "kv",
        "vault-value": "sabrinaTest"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Best regards.
